# Selecting input check[ed]box and adding style to its parent

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm selecting a checkbox and adding style to its parent tag. It's working well. What I don't know is how to do the inverse way, when it is already checked and remove the style.

http://jsfiddle.net/FG7jV/

HTML

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="" value="" /></td>
            <td><img src="http://lorempixel.com/60/60/" /></td>
                    <td>Boné NFL - San Diego Charges</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
 </table>
```

JQUERY

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
$(this).parent().parent().css("background-color","yellow");
});
$("input:checked").click(function(){
alert();
});
```

im using alert, obviously, just to check if it's selecting when i click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this (Use `change` event):

```
$("input:checkbox").change(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parent().parent().css("background-color","yellow");
    }
    else {
        $(this).parent().parent().css("background-color","");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to check if the checkbox is checked onclick:

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
    if(!$(this).prop("checked"))
        alert();
    else
        $(this).parent().parent().css("background-color","yellow");
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FG7jV/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
var isChecked = $(this).attr('checked')?true:false;
if(isChecked){
$(this).parent().parent().css("background-color","yellow");
}
else
     $(this).parent().parent().css("background-color","");
});
```